# Add object component without Replace the old component - To make JSON Array

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, json

I want to make JSON array using jQuery and got some problem:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo - Push Data Object</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
            var obj = new Object();

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#add").click(function() {
                    item('Item 1', '1000');
                    item('Item 2', '2000');
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
                });
            });

            function item(itemNo, price) {
                obj.itemNo = itemNo;
                obj.price = price;
            };
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input id="add" type="button" value="Add Object" />
    </body>
</html>
```

When the button `add` is click it will print:
`{"itemNo":"Item 2","price":"2000"}`.

What I want to achieve is like this one:

```
{
    {
        "itemNo":"Item 1",
        "price":"1000"
    }, 
    {
        "itemNo":"Item 2",
        "price":"2000"
    }
}
```

**What I'm supposed to change in code above?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desired output isn't valid JSON; since you have a list of items, the outer brackets should be `[ ]`. The following code generates that ([**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/w9sBh/)):

```
var objs = [];

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add").click(function() {
        objs.push(item('Item 1', '1000'));
        objs.push(item('Item 2', '2000'));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(objs));
    });
});

function item(itemNo, price) {
    return { 
        itemNo : itemNo,
        price : price
    };
};
```

---

Output:

```
[
    {
        "itemNo":"Item 1",
        "price":"1000"
    }, 
    {
        "itemNo":"Item 2",
        "price":"2000"
    }
]
```